# Keras. Нейронные сети. Данные mnist. Распознавать под разным фоном

Tags: python, keras

Я использую keras для обучения сверточной нейронной сети. Обучаю её распознавать цифры с набора mnist. Распознает в принципе нормально, но если сменить фон цифры с черного на какой то другой, перестает распознавать. Использую модель следующей архитектуры:

```
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(24,(3,3),activation='relu',input_shape=(28,28,1)))
    mode l.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
    model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(128,activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(10,activation='softmax'))

 model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics['accuracy'])
```

Не подскажите как можно кастомизировать фон цифры? Что бы можно было распознать под любым фоном

Comment: а зачем вы меняете фон у черно-белой картинки? Обычно при распознавании наоборот первым делом преобразовывают картинку в черно-белую (градации серого)

Comment: Я делаю так:    img = image.load_img(name,target_size=(28,28),grayscale=True)
    img = image.img_to_array(img)
    img = img.astype('float32')
    img/=255.0

Comment: img = np.expand_dims(img,axis=0). Я сам рисую картинку, и потом пытаюсь её распознать. Так вот, с фоном отличным от черного, не работает

Comment: Я у тому что нейронка распознает цифры только на черном фоне. На практике это не катит вообще.

Comment: Можете выложить несколько собственных картинок?

Comment: https://ibb.co/JqGzcN7
https://ibb.co/28bXQyz

Comment: С белым фоном не распознается, а с черном распознается.

Comment: нейросеть обучена таким образом, что  распознаваться будут только черно-белые картинки на черном фоне размерности `(28,28)`. Т.е. вам придется конвертировать все картинки в картинки с описанными характеристиками

Comment: https://medium.com/@o.kroeger/tensorflow-mnist-and-your-own-handwritten-digits-4d1cd32bbab4

Comment: Надо что ли сделать все варианты цифр с разными фонами? Как по другому сделать?

Comment: нет, надо все "пользовательские" картинки привести к виду с черным фоном и белой цифрой, чтобы получилось как в обучающем наборе